# How to order dataframe based in the legth of the vector that the cell contains in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, statistics

I want to order the "StarWars" data frame based on the number of film appearances. As you can see the "film" column contains a vector with the films. Which is the best approach to do this?
[image]

Comment: Does the provided solution sovle your problem? If so, please consider accepting the answer so that others can benefit from that information as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

starwars %>%
  arrange(-lengths(films))
```

`lengths` gives you the number of elements in a list. Since the `films` column is a list column, this function helps.

And once we have the number of elements per row, we can simply sort/`arrange` by that information.

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Comment: Sorry, didn't have the time earlier on.